# How to make bar plot with dplyr in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, ggplot2, shinydashboard

I am trying to make a bar plot in renderUI in shiny dashboard. Following is my code

```
output$city_plot <- renderUI({

clean_data(data) %>% 
  group_by(registrant_city) %>%
  summarise(Total= n()) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Total)) %>% 
  ggplot(data=clean_data(data),aes(x= registrant_city, y = Total)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill= registrant_city), position = "dodge", stat = "identity") 


})
```

`clean_data` is a function which returns a dataframe after cleaning and munging of a dataframe

Whenever I run shiny app it gives me `Error:Mapping should be created with`aes() or `aes_()`.` I do not know what exactly this means. When I run the same code in R console it gives me a proper ootput.

```
data%>%
  group_by(registrant_city) %>%
  summarise(Total = n())    %>%
  arrange(desc(Total))      %>%
  top_n(n = 10)             %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= registrant_city, y = Total)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill=registrant_city), position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

What I am doing wrong? please help

Comment: This is not exactly same code : you don't use `clean_data()` in the console run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it where i was committing a mistake, in `ui.R` file instead of `uiOutput` I changed it to `plotOutput` and in the `server.R` file I changed it to `renderPlot`

Now everything works fine.